# Parsing URL's from JavaScript driven page with Beautifulsoup and Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I want to parse all URL's in Git repository where any e-mails occur.
I use https://grep.app

The code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://grep.app/search?current=100&q=%40gmail.com'
chrome = "/home/dev/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome)
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
tags = soup.select('a')
print(tags)
```

When code started, Chrome started and page with results are loaded and in Developers tools in Chrome, in source code I can see a lot of A and HREF for URL's.
[Source from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETy9H.png)

Like:
[lib/plugins/revert/lang/eu/lang.php](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/master/lib/plugins/revert/lang/eu/lang.php)

But my code return only "tags" from footer:

```
"[<a href="/"><span class="slashes">//</span>grep.app</a>, <a href="mailto:hello@grep.app">Contact</a>]"
```

As I understand something wrong with JS parsing.
Please advise what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://grep.app/search?current=100&q=%40gmail.com'
chrome = "/home/dev/chromedriver"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome)
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

links = []
tags = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for tag in tags:
    links.append(tag['href'])
    
print(links)
```

Output:

```
['/', 'mailto:hello@grep.app']
```

Comment: John, thanks, but it's the same output as I got from my code.
There is nothing like real URL to files.